# one solution depends on another solution dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependency-properties, solution

My solution builds another solution in a pre-build step - takes the artifacts to itself as a "deployment folder".

My references are at the dll level assuming the files are there.

The weird thing is that any new code I write in the first solution (for example change method name) is ignored by the the second solution that depends on the first.

I tried many things like clean solution, rebuild, disable the QTagent between tests and everything. seems like he remembers the first snapshot of the class and that's it - won't takle any changes when I try to debug.

What is the best way to work between solution so code can be called in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the original project (of solution 1) in your solution (2), then in the main project you add a reference to the referenced original project. Visual Studio takes care of the rest.

This looks like:
[Example http://imageshack.us/a/img11/7493/57388651.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img11/7493/57388651.png)

If you're using it to run tests, then you can add the test project to the original solution. With the default Visual Studio Unit testing this'd look like:
[Example 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img39/3590/25226157.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img39/3590/25226157.png)

Comment: forgot to mention that the second solution is system tests (based on MSTest) - so it tests the first solution. no main here ;) just tests. I have the relevant "using" but it will not detect any code changes...

Comment: The answer doesn't change at all actually, it doesn't require a `main`. If you have SP1 installed, try creating a ASP.Net MVC 3 application, it'll ask you if it should add a test project for it, those tests will run perfectly without an actual `main` :)

Comment: When adding references just add the other project. Otherwise you will have to copy and paste the dll every time.

Comment: @MrFox Exactly, and VS takes care of keeping the built up-to-date.